# How to create Category separated Listview builder using flutter

Tags: flutter-listview

I was trying to create a Listview with Category and could not find any solution. I need some help with this.

```
List<Product> products = [
{
  "ProductID":"1234",
  "ProductName":"Milk",
  "ProductCategory":"Dairy",
},
{
  "ProductID":"12345",
  "ProductName":"Apple",
  "ProductCategory":"Fruits",
},{
  "ProductID":"12342",
  "ProductName":"Chicken",
  "ProductCategory":"Meat",
},{
  "ProductID":"123422",
  "ProductName":"Eggs",
  "ProductCategory":"Dairy",
},
{
  "ProductID":"1234222",
  "ProductName":"Bread",
  "ProductCategory":"Dairy",
}


];
```

How can I separate this `ListView` by category?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list

Answer (score 0):

You may use a small hack or we can say a workaround here.First create a ListView and then by using data from future take out categories and put it in HashMap so that categories will be unique. Then create a widget (  ListView.builder ) for each category which is taken from HashMap and display all the data.